# Problem regarding use of constructors in PHP

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, constructor

My problem is in using Codeigniter custom library but I think it is not specific to that and more related to use of constructors in PHP.
I am trying to create a custom controller library in Codeigniter like this...

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller {
    var $data = array();

    function MY_Controller() {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->data['err'] = 'no';

        $this->load->helper('utilities');
    }
}
```

Now I create a codeigniter controller class like this...

```
class api_controller extends MY_Controller {
    function get_data() {
        $this->data['view'] = "data";
        $this->load->view("data_view", $this->data);
    }
    function get_xml() {
        $this->data['part'] = "xml";
        $this->load->view("data_view", $this->data);
    }
}
```

I want to ask that if the controller class extending the `MY_Controller` is instantiated when I access urls like `api_controller/get_data` and `api_controller/get_xml`, does the constructor of parent class always get called upon, i.e., `MY_Controller()` is always called.

Am I correct in inferring the following

```
get_data() called
-> $data => array ('err' => 'no', 'view' => 'data')

get_xml() called
-> $data => array ('err' => 'no', 'part' => 'xml')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks like it's using the PHP4 syntax for constructors. You should switch to the PHP5 syntax.

PHP4:

```
class MyClassName {
    function MyClassName() {...}  //constructor.
}
```

PHP5:

```
class MyClassName {
    function __construct() {...}  //constructor.
}
```

You can then call the constructor of a parent class by calling `parent::__constructor();` from within the child class's `__constructor()` method:

```
class MyClassName extends SomeOtherClass {
    function __construct() {
        //...code here runs before the parent constructor.
        parent::__construct();
        //...code here runs after the parent constructor.
    }
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to CI 2.0 for proper use of __construct() all the way through or some versions of PHP will not handle the constructors properly. Some versions can have __construct() map to PHP4-style Controller, but CI 2.0 just removes all PHP 4 style constructors.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP in general the parent constructor is not called default if the child has a constructor.
[Constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). It can be called using parent::_construct();

If you're using php 5+ you should go with the new recommended style of using function __construct() instead of the old style with a function named the same as a class.

As for CI-specific stuff I can't help you, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not override `__construct()` in `MY_Controller` then `Controller`'s `__construct()` will get run.

If you override it and then called `parent::__construct()` then it will run your own and the parent's.

So if you wanted it to run the parent's and your own you would do this

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller 
{
    var $data = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the parent constructor it is always called (you may want to rewrite them as __construct() however, thinking also at codeigniter 2.0 ).
If you really are in doubt toss in it an `echo` and see it for yourself.

Also the $this->data part is correct to me

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your affirmations about the data array contents. In you code you wrote:

```
function MY_Controller() {
    parent::Controller();
```

so the parents's class constructor is being called. There are lots of comments about PHP4 and PHP5 syntax, but basically everithing is ok.

In your question you wrote

> that if the controller class extending the MY_Controller is instantiated

that is not correct. The instance is an object of class api_controller, calling the MY_Controller constructor is made using the same object. That is not the same, that is basic for polimorphism.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            // Your own constructor code
       }
}
```